# PHP str_replace is not replacing "escape chars"

Tags: php

I want to replace **escape chars** in my string to **html chars**. For instance "`\n\r`" to "`<br>`" for a line break.

```
$message = "A\r\n\r\nB";
$message = str_replace('\r\n','<br>',$message);
error_log($message);
```

The output is `A\r\n\r\nB` and not `A<br><br>B`.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: `'\r\n'` is not the same as `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Like [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php) ?

Comment: Thanks Olivier. Can you write the comment as an answer? So I can close this question.